# How to close a Java JFrame based on action event from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

How would I go about closing a `JFrame` based on an `ActionEvent` from a button click within a `JPanel`?

I have a total of three classes:

- `Application`: contains the main method and runs the program by creating a `FrameStartUp` object.
- `FrameStartUp`: extends the `JFrame` class and displays the contents within `StartUpPanel`.
- `StartUpPanel`: extends the `JPanel` class and has all the components and `ActionEvents`.

Within the `StartUpPanel` class, I have a button with an `ActionEventListener` waiting for the button to be clicked.

When the button is clicked I want the application to shut down completely.  I know of a method called `.dispose()` for the `JFrame` class, but I can't use it because creating an object of `FrameStartUp` would just run another GUI (run by the constructor).

As I am new to programming and swing, I do not know any other way to fix this, other than getting rid of the `StartUpPanel` and just creating a `JPanel` within the `FrameStartUp` class.

Are there any methods provided by Swing that can access the current `JFrame` that the panel is on, so the program can close when the `ActionEvent` is triggered?

Comment: See [The use of multiple JFrames, Good / Bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) (bad), it creates a terrible UX, your task bar could be filled with multiple windows and confuse your user. You could use `JPanels` and `Dialogs` instead or use [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). For better help sooner post a proper [mre]

Comment: `System.exit(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know of a method called `.dispose()` for the `JFrame` class

This will work if you explicitly set `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

> Are there any methods provided by Swing that can access the current `JFrame` that the panel is on

Yes... `SwingUtilities` provides one called `getWindowAncestor()`.

```java
button.addActionListener(e -> {
   SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component)e.getSource()).dispose();
});
```

... or more commonly, you can chose to reference a `final` variable to achieve the same effect...

```java
final JFrame swingStuff = this; // or expose via a getter/setter
button.addActionListener(e -> {
   swingStuff.dispose();
});
```

... however the `final` variable placement and setter/getter would need a small reproducible code example.

And finally, as others have mentioned, `System.exit(0)` works quite fantastically well too, so as long as it doesn't break the lifecycle of any of your other components.

My test class:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingStuff extends JFrame {
    // Our main JFrame
    public SwingStuff() {
        super();

        // The button
        JButton button = new JButton("Close");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component)e.getSource()).dispose();
        });

        // The JPanel and nested components
        JPanel startupPanel = new JPanel();
        startupPanel.add(button);
        add(startupPanel);
        pack();

        // Make sure the app exits when closed
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    // Just our entry point
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new SwingStuff().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```